# convert int to char without itoa()

Tags: c++, file, char

i have a program and i should convert int to char into it

but i cant use itoa() because site's judge don't support it

so i wrote this:

```
xt[i]= rmn+'0';
```

but i get this error :

```
Runtime error: Illegal file open (/dev/tty)
```

How should i convert this?

My code is this : (for palsquare question of USACO)

```
/*
ID: sa.13781
PROG: palsquare
LANG: C++
*/
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;


ofstream fout("palsquare.out");

int tool(char xt[])//CORRECT
{
    int p = 0;
    while (xt[p] != 0)
        p++;
    return p;
}

void prt(char xt[])//CORRECT
{
    int p = 0;
    while (xt[p] != 0)
    {
        fout << xt[p];
        p++;
    }
}

void mabna(int a, char xt[], int mab)
{
    int ex = 1, tavan = 0, rmn, n;
    for (; ex <= a; ex *= mab)
        tavan++;

    for (int i = tavan - 1; a != 0; i--, a /= mab)
    {
        rmn = a % mab;

        switch (rmn)
        {
        case 0:
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3:
        case 4:
        case 5:
        case 6:
        case 7:
        case 8:
        case 9:
            xt[i] = rmn + '0';
            break;
        case 10:
            xt[i] = 'A';
            break;
        case 11:
            xt[i] = 'B';
            break;
        case 12:
            xt[i] = 'C';
            break;
        case 13:
            xt[i] = 'D';
            break;
        case 14:
            xt[i] = 'E';
            break;
        case 15:
            xt[i] = 'F';
            break;
        case 16:
            xt[i] = 'G';
            break;
        case 17:
            xt[i] = 'H';
            break;
        case 18:
            xt[i] = 'I';
            break;
        case 19:
            xt[i] = 'J';
            break;
        }
    }
}

bool mirror(char *xt)//CORRECT
{
    int p = 0;
    int n = tool(xt);
    for (int i = 0; i < (n / 2); i++)
        if (xt[i] == xt[n - i - 1])
            p++;
    if (p == (n / 2))
        return true;
    return false;
}

void calc(int mab) //CORRECT
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 300; i++)
    {

        char p[10] = {0}, p2[10] = {0};
        mabna(i * i, p2, mab);
        if ( mirror(p2) == true )
        {
            mabna(i, p, mab);
            prt(p);
            fout << " ";
            prt(p2);
            fout << "\n";
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    ifstream fin("palsquare.in");

    int mab;
    fin >> mab;
    calc(mab);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Your question will attract answers more successfully if you follow the advice here:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .   As it stands, it is being downvoted because it does not meet the guidelines of that page, and more generally here http://stackoverflow.com/help .

Comment: `iota` is a non-standard function. I'm not surprised the site doesn't support it.

Comment: Anyway, the "runtime error" you're receiving means that your program is crashing (and the website doesn't tell you that). Learn how to debug your code, we can't do it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `int` value is single digit, you can just cast it with `(char)`
If your `int` value is more than one digit, you can never expect a single `char` to hold it. `char` can only hold single character.

```
int num = 7;
char ch = (num + 48);  //same effect as + '0'
cout << ch << endl;
```

**OUTPUT: 7**

---

If your `int` value is more than single digit. You need char* or char[] to hold the converted data. For example:

```
int num = 123987;
int len = 6;
int idx = len-1;;
char ch[20];

while(num > 0)
{
    ch[idx] = (num%10) + 48;
    num /= 10;
    idx --;         
}

for(int x=0; x<len; x++)
    cout << "OUTPUT in char: " << ch[x];
```

**OUTPUT in char: 123987**

This is not a perfectly good way to handle this kind of situation, but it may gives you what you asked for.

Comment: i used this but i just get answers like this: @ @ @

Answer (score 5):

Can you use sprintf()?

```
char s[16];
int x = 15;
sprintf(s, "%d", x);
```

Comment: Or, unless you're a C+ programmer (http://powerfield-software.com/?p=829), use stringstreams :-)

Comment: i want to convert int to char...not char*